# I am unable to suggest edits

Tags: support

I suggested some edits which were rejected yesterday. Since then, I am not able to suggest anymore edits. I wonder, how can I lift this ban?

Comment: Scott Milner did an excellent job of explaining the ban. I will speak to why your edits were rejected. In short you were adding tags that were irrelevant. Take [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/51864) as an example. That question is asking about naming objects, it has nothing to do with selection-tools, python, or scripting. That is why your edits were rejected, and thus auto blocking you from suggesting any more.

Comment: I lifted the ban since it was a first time offense and your intentions were well intended if a little misconstrued as to how we approach tagging here. We love edits but prefer those that make the question better in terms of readability and or visibility. It's a tentative topic and oft lies with one's best judgement for vague posts hence why we confirm these for low rep users. So picking seemingly related keywords to tag a question isn't how it's done. Try to deduce what tags a question merits by what the asker **wants**, not what you think it will entail or possible ways to do it.

Comment: @iKlsR Thank you so much! Will be more careful next times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/357942) on **Meta.SE**:

> You [can be] banned from suggesting edits, either automatically because a large number of recent suggested edits by you were rejected, a moderator manually banned you, or you triggered the anonymous insta-ban filter.

It appears that you fall under the first of these categories, "a large number of recent suggested edits by you were rejected." **This ban will last for seven days, after which you will be able to suggest edits again like normal.**

---

The formula used to mete out edit bans can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/357942):

> When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last **7 days** of activity.
>
> If `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5`, you will be auto-banned.

Looking at [your recent suggestions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29301/amir?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), it appears that you have 2 approved suggestions and 5 rejections. Interestingly, this doesn't fit the formula: `5-(2/3) == 4.333`. Perhaps the formula has changed since 2011, when that post was made.