# I suddenly appear unable to suggest tag entry edits. Does anyone know why?

Tags: discussion, tags

According to [this question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/i-am-unable-to-suggest-edits) there are three reasons to ban someone from making tag edit suggestions and two of them definitely don't apply:

1. *because a large number of recent suggested edits by you were rejected*  - Doesn't apply; I haven't had any suggestions rejected at all.
2. *you triggered the anonymous insta-ban filter* - All of my edits have been logged in. None are anonymous.

That only leaves

3. *a moderator manually banned you*

or the possibility that there's a 4th reason not given in that answer.  Does anyone know why I can't propose edits?

Comment: I believe there is a limit (5) to how many proposed tag/ tag wiki edits can be pending before the system blocks further edits. I've approved them, you should be able to continue editing now.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info and the approvals.  I was sure there was an option 4, but I thought I only had two pending.

Comment: Relevant MSE post: [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/335251)

Comment: That's slightly misleading, in that if you are at 4 and submit an edit for both a summary and its tag wiki at the same time you end up with 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is from [Timaroberts](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15924/timaroberts) in the comments:

> I believe there is a limit (5) to how many proposed tag/ tag wiki edits can be pending before the system blocks further edits.